# django-haystack & solr: rebuild_index not adding models to index

Tags: solr, django-haystack

How can I get my models included in the index for `rebuild_index`?

Running **python manage.py rebuild_index -v2** outputs this:

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Permission'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.sites.models.Site'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'myapp.models.Article'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'myapp.models.Source'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'taggit.models.Tag'>' - no index.
Skipping '<class 'taggit.models.TaggedItem'>' - no index.
```

Of the above, `myapp.models.Article` should be included. I have this in **myproject/myapp/search_index.py**:

```py
from haystack import indexes
from myapp.models import Article    

class ArticleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)        

def get_model(self):
    return Article

def index_queryset(self, using=None):        
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

I'm running **django 1.5**, **solr 4** and **haystack 2.0** on an **sqlite3** database. In my googling I've seen people experiencing a similar problem with xapian & whoosh, with no solutions provided thus far. I feel like it could be haystack's new version, or my sqlite3 database. Anyone understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

search_index.py ? Is it a typo because it should be search_indexes.py . Isn't it . If you using correct name then please elaborate a little .

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful link that I found too late: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging.html